# Likert scale coding

Tags: likert

I have a question on coding a Likert scale in SPSS.

Assuming we have a 7-point Likert scale, a "well-being" score may rank from 1 through 7.

While doing some reading on multi-variate analysis, I've come across a reference that suggests a "deviation score".   That is, it's ranging from [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3].

For later analysis of survey results, which method ("well-being score" vs. "deviation score") will serve me best?    Or are these "apples and oranges"?

Thanks,
EEH

Answer (score 3):

More like apples and apples.

For most purposes, it won't make any difference in the results, only in how they are interpreted. That can be important. One exception is if you wanted to add a quadratic of the Likert scale.

If you tell us more about what you are doing (e.g. is this the dependent variable? Independent variable? Or just something you are describing (e.g. with frequencies, median, etc) we will be able to give more detailed advice.

Comment: All "extent" question are referenced to the independent variables.   There will be a few question for the dependent variables; however, I won't apply Likert scales for the DV-related questions.   Based on the answers from the IV questions, I'd like to proof/disproof the hypotheses.   Did that help?

Comment: Sure, that makes me more sure that my answer applies to your case.

Comment: Thanks... could you please elaborate on "... only in how they are interpreted.  That can be important."?

Comment: It's more important when it's the DV, I think. When it's the IV in a regression, you are mostly interested in how a change affects the DV.